# Ошибка при нахождении среднего арифметического

Tags: javascript

Есть функция для нахождения среднего арифметического:

```
function average() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments[i]; i++ ) sum += arguments[i];
    return sum == 0 ? sum : sum / arguments.length;
}
```

Если пишем так: `average(2, 5, 5, 5);`
Получаем: 4,25

Вроде все хорошо, но если написать: `average(5, 5, 5, 2);`
Получаем: 3.75

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так и как исправить?

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно, с чем вы сравниваете i в цикле

Comment: Вы лучше бы rest параметры бы использовали.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## ES5

```js
function average() {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) sum += arguments[i];
  return sum && sum / arguments.length;
}

console.log(average(5, 5, 5, 2))
console.log(average(5, -5))
console.log(average(0))
console.log(average())
```

## ES6

```js
function average(...args) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var x of args) sum += x;
  return sum && sum / args.length;
}

console.log(average(5, 5, 5, 2))
console.log(average(5, -5))
console.log(average(0))
console.log(average())
```

Comment: Очень хороший ответ.

Answer (score 3):

```
function average(...args) {
    return args.reduce((sum, i) => sum + i, 0) / args.length || 0;
}
```

Совсем уж фриковый, но интересный способ нашел на подобном вопросе в глобальном SO. По записи короче всего.

```
function average(...args) {
     return eval(args.join('+')) / args.length || 0;
}
```

Comment: `+=` вполне заменяется на `+`

Comment: Согласен, поправил. Спасибо

Comment: args не массив а объект, join не будет работать

Comment: для преобразования объекта arguments в обычный массив можно использовать метод Array.from()

Comment: вы о чем? запустите в консоли и проверьте, что такое args

Comment: если у вас так работает не значит что на всех движках JS это будет работать так же

Comment: значит просто внимательно перечитайте код. увидите упоминание `arguments` - покажите всем. ну а потом, такие вещи, как `arguments` и `rest`/`spread` операторы регламентируются спецификацией языка. И если JS движок трактует живой стандарт по-своему, значит он мертворожденный.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function average() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ){
       sum += arguments[i]
    };
    return sum == 0 ? sum : sum / arguments.length;
}

console.log(average(5, 5, 5, 2))
```

Вы допустили ошибку в условии цикла:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arguments[i]; i++ ){
       sum += arguments[i]
  };
```

Цикл выполнялся до тех пор, пока *i* меньше за *i-тый элемент*.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

1. **arguments** - [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).
2. Старайтесь не помещать в циклы операции типа: `args.length`.
3. Используйте `===`

```js
function average(...args) {
    let sum = 0;
    let args_length = args.length;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < args_length; i++ ) {
      sum += args[i];
    }
    
    return sum === 0 ? sum : sum / args_length;
}

console.log(average(5, 5, 5, 2));
console.log(average(2, 5, 5, 5));
```

Comment: Понять не могу, это описка или вы так и хотели? args и arguments?

Comment: @АлександрЛесив Я не считаю это лишним. И не известно в каких броузерах будет исполнятся код.

Comment: @Yugofx были опечатки. Поправил. `arguments`  - зарезервированное слово.

Comment: @АлександрЛесив + я сэкономил одно вычисление. Странно что минусуют))

Comment: Не странно, вы используете `rest` оператор, дающий массив, и `arguments` в одной функции

Comment: @Yugofx Поправил, Спать надо идти). Спасибо

Comment: где написано, что _arguments - deprecated._?

Comment: @АлександрЛесив О_о Что значит "выносят условие из цикла"? По определению цикла, оно и должно проверяться перед каждой итерацией, нет?)

Comment: 1. Ну не так уж и deprecated. 2. Неактуально уже давно. 3. Интересный костыль - проверять сумму вместо числа элементов, но работать будет и даже есть шансы, что немного оптимальнее. Но сравнение из условия стоит вообще выкинуть: `sum && sum / args_length`. 4. Если уж rest, то можно было бы и for-of применить.

Comment: в PHP количество элементов массива вычисляется функцией count(array) и там действительно в циклах лучше избегать повторных вычислений передав количество элементов в переменную и используя её, здесь же вы этим ничего не поменяете только создадите ещё одну переменную потому что вы же не пишете args.length() тогда это действительно была бы функция надеюсь вы поняли о чём я

Comment: @Qwertiy По первому, почему не так уж? Поясните второй пункт, почему не актуально? Все все движки уже понимают такие ситуации? По 3-му пункту не понял, почему костыль? С 4 согласен).

Comment: @IvaMuxa, в Опере 12 использование `arr.length` в условии цикла по сравнению с вынесенной переменной удваивало время суммирования элементов массива. Вероятно, у старых IE та же проблема. Во всех современных браузерах влияния на производительность нет совсем. @doox911, вот поэтому неактуально. Вот for-of да, некоторое время назад был медленнее (сейчас не в курсе), а с length я не знаю более новых движков, которые бы не оптимизировали его. Если знаешь, назови.

Comment: @doox911, ну да, rest поудобнее, от него не надо отрезать куски чтобы пропустить обязательные параметры и он массив. А arguments попадает в замыкание лямбды. Но вот чтобы их прям явно объявили устаревшими - вроде не помню такого.

Comment: @doox911, ну может правильнее было назвать хаком. Cреднее - это сумма всех элементов, делённая на количество - и неважно, 0 она или нет. Если 100 элементов дают сумму 0, то среднее всё равно 0/100 = 0. Но есть нюанс - когда элементов 0. По идее, проверка должна выглядеть так: `args.length ? sum/args.length : 0`. Но т. к. в таком случае sum уже 0, а если 0 на что-то (кроме 0) поделить, то получится тоже 0, вместо args.length проверяется sum - довольно неожиданно. Но если задуматься, мы экономим обращение к свойству и, иногда, деление, да и запись получается покрасивее: `sum && sum/args.length`.

Comment: пять лет назад у IE было всего около 10% сегодня им уже не пользуются вообще

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо.

Comment: @IvaMuxa, насколько я помню, в IE11 разницы уже не было. Там должны быть старее версии.